# NSString drawInRect : text is not clipped to the given height

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, nsstring, uikit

I am drawing a text using NSString drawInRect function  like the following

```
[nsStrToDraw drawInRect:cgRect withFont:uiFont lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap alignment: UITextAlignmentLeft];
```

//nsStrToDraw is "Enter"
//uiFont size is 32
//and cgRect is (100 , 100 , 100 , 20);

the problem is that even though the bounding rectangle's (cgRect)  height is 20, the text is not getting clipped to the given height and it drawn with whatever height it fits to.

NOTE: the text gets clipped to the given width though, just that it doesnt seem to clip to given height.

Any thoughts on how to address this ?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your own clipping rect before you draw the text, using [`CGContextClipToRect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextClipToRect).

Comment: thanks, i had that thought too .. i was wondering if this could be fixed in the drawInRect function itself or if there is any other way .. looks like there is none.

Answer (score 0):

`UIView`s don't clip their content unless you set `clipsToBounds = YES`.